# double clicking in the JComboBox results in a strange error

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have a strange problem. I'm working on a long program and in that program I create a JComboBox the following way:

```
String[] s = {"aa", "bb", "cc"};
JComboBox try1 = new JComboBox(s);
try1.insertItemAt("", 0);
try1.setSelectedIndex(0);
AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(try1);
```

When I run the program, if the user double clicks inside the text area of the combo box I get the following runtime error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.text.PlainDocument cannot be cast to javax.swing.text.StyledDocument
at org.jdesktop.swingx.autocomplete.AutoCompleteDocument.getParagraphElement(AutoCompleteDocument.java:309)
at javax.swing.text.Utilities.getParagraphElement(Utilities.java:850)
at javax.swing.text.Utilities.getWordStart(Utilities.java:631)
at javax.swing.text.DefaultEditorKit$BeginWordAction.actionPerformed(DefaultEditorKit.java:1750)
at javax.swing.text.DefaultEditorKit$SelectWordAction.actionPerformed(DefaultEditorKit.java:2163)
at javax.swing.text.DefaultCaret.selectWord(DefaultCaret.java:390)
at javax.swing.text.DefaultCaret.mousePressed(DefaultCaret.java:495)
at com.apple.laf.AquaCaret.mousePressed(AquaCaret.java:140)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mousePressed(AWTEventMulticaster.java:280)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6502)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4489)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.text.PlainDocument cannot be cast to javax.swing.text.StyledDocument
at org.jdesktop.swingx.autocomplete.AutoCompleteDocument.getParagraphElement(AutoCompleteDocument.java:309)
at javax.swing.text.Utilities.getParagraphElement(Utilities.java:850)
at javax.swing.text.Utilities.getWordStart(Utilities.java:631)
at javax.swing.text.DefaultEditorKit$BeginWordAction.actionPerformed(DefaultEditorKit.java:1750)
at javax.swing.text.DefaultEditorKit$SelectWordAction.actionPerformed(DefaultEditorKit.java:2163)
at javax.swing.text.DefaultCaret.selectWord(DefaultCaret.java:390)
at javax.swing.text.DefaultCaret.mouseClicked(DefaultCaret.java:415)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(AWTEventMulticaster.java:270)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6508)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4501)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

However, if I create a very simple program that contains nothing but the same JComboBox I do not have the same problem. I find this very strange because the JComboBox is not being used anywhere so far in my program. Can someone please tell me what might be causing this behaviour. Thanks.

Comment: What is `AutoCompleteDecorator`?  You're problem may lie there.

Comment: It allows the user to start typing the first few letters and the list will automatically jump to that part. I don't think the problem is there because I used it in the simple program and nothing went wrong.

Comment: Can we see the ActionListener, or related code?

Comment: if you disable the 'AutoCompleteDecorator' (outcomment the line), is the error still present?

Comment: Does this `AutoCompleteDecorator` belong to [SwingX](https://swingx.java.net/) project? If so then your code works perfectly to me without any error on double-click the editable area. By the way I'm using SwingX 1.6.4 (last version).

Comment: If I disable AutoCompleteDecorator then the problem is no longer there. But it that case, why didn't it cause the same problem in the simpler program?

Comment: @user3245747 post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). Follow the link, it explains you exactly how to track down your issue and provide a smaller piece of code demonstrating your issue. Otherwise, you are just looking for random, probably mostly incorrect, answers

Comment: Holy smokes - I misspelled "your" in the first comment. Somebody smack me with a wet mackerel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution:

The problem was caused by the `AutoCompleteDecorator`. I deactivated it and used instead the `AutoCompletion.enable(employeeDelete)`. I appreciate all the comments that helped me.